# Arel gem: "SELECT *" missing from where clause in rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have searched far and wide for the answer to this question, apparently nobody in the entire world has ever had this problem. I am using these gems:

ruby 1.9.3p551
rails (4.2.5.1, 4.2.5)
arel (6.0.3)
arel-helpers (2.2.0)

Here is the syntax that I am using in my controller:

```
table = Arel::Table.new(:table)
query = table.where( u[:column].eq(current_user.id) )
@rows = Conversation.find_by_sql( query.to_sql )
```

This is the error I get when loading that page

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `table` WHERE `table`.`row` = 1' at line 1: SELECT FROM `table` WHERE `table`.`row` = 1
```

Specifically you can see this:

```
SELECT FROM `table` WHERE `table`.`row` = 1
```

As you can see the '*' is missing from 'SELECT * FROM' where did it go? Why isn't it there? How can I add it without parsing the string manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#project` for this, like this:

```
users = Arel::Table.new(:users)
users.where(users[:email].eq('jon@doe.com')).project('*').to_sql
 => "SELECT * FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"email\" = 'jon@doe.com'"
```

Instead of hardcoding `*` in there, you can use `Arel.star`, like this

```
Arel::Table.new(:users).where(users[:email].eq('...')).project(Arel.star).to_sql
```